# Python and matplotlib: Equal vertical spacing of superscript and subscript characters (using Arial) in a plot's legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, subscript, superscript

With my last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222659/making-pythons-matplotlib-graphics-look-like-graphics-created-using-originpro) in mind, I need some more help with matplotlib graphics and fonts. With the friendly help of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest), I was able to create plots in Python, but superscript characters have a higher vertical space or padding than subscript characters (see figure 1) using Arial, apparently. I would like to continue using Arial, but super- and subscript characters to be aligned normally (see figure 2). My minimal working example is as follows:

```
# MWE - python 3.6.4 / 3.7.2

import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Arial']
rcParams['font.size'] = 15

# labels in TeX-format are given in a different file in the original program

label_list=["[MX_4(^AY)_4]^-", "[MX(^AY)_4]^-"]

output_array = np.genfromtxt("oa.txt", dtype=float, delimiter=" ")

for ion in range(len(label_list)):
    plt.plot(output_array[:,0], output_array[:,ion], marker="s",label=r"$\mathregular{%s}$" % (label_list[ion-1]))
    plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

The data used is:

> 0.000000000000000000e+00 4.127290260366441865e-01 5.872709739633558135e-01
>   1.000000000000000000e+00 2.891558566042558565e-01 7.108441433957440880e-01
>   2.000000000000000000e+00 1.979585968947671082e-01 8.020414031052328641e-01
>   3.000000000000000000e+00 1.238903898108838220e-01 8.761096101891161503e-01
>   4.000000000000000000e+00 6.903086085544125894e-02 9.309691391445586994e-01
>   5.000000000000000000e+00 3.809897879025923167e-02 9.619010212097407475e-01
>   6.000000000000000000e+00 2.185727788279773209e-02 9.781427221172023234e-01
>   7.000000000000000000e+00 1.441899915182357980e-02 9.855810008481764584e-01
>   8.000000000000000000e+00 9.900990099009901110e-03 9.900990099009900902e-01
>   9.000000000000000000e+00 1.037181996086105652e-02 9.896281800391389938e-01
>   1.000000000000000000e+01 1.068883610451306330e-02 9.893111638954869003e-01
>   1.100000000000000000e+01 4.562043795620437589e-03 9.954379562043795815e-01
>   1.200000000000000000e+01 1.573033707865168634e-02 9.842696629213483206e-01
>   1.300000000000000000e+01 1.270588235294117622e-02 9.872941176470588776e-01
>   1.400000000000000000e+01 1.210121012101210078e-02 9.878987898789879374e-01
>   1.500000000000000000e+01 8.961911874533233513e-03 9.910380881254667873e-01
>   1.600000000000000000e+01 2.255639097744360777e-02 9.774436090225563367e-01
>   1.700000000000000000e+01 2.549575070821529649e-02 9.745042492917846966e-01
>   1.800000000000000000e+01 2.564102564102564014e-02 9.743589743589743390e-01
>   1.900000000000000000e+01 5.647058823529411964e-02 9.435294117647058387e-01
>   2.000000000000000000e+01 4.780876494023904300e-02 9.521912350597609986e-01
>   2.000000000000000000e+01 1.010452961672473893e-01 8.989547038327526662e-01
>   1.800000000000000000e+01 4.583333333333333010e-02 9.541666666666667185e-01
>   1.600000000000000000e+01 1.441812564366632375e-02 9.855818743563337092e-01
>   1.400000000000000000e+01 2.482678983833718281e-02 9.751732101616628068e-01
>   1.200000000000000000e+01 1.406309388065374311e-02 9.859369061193462569e-01
>   1.000000000000000000e+01 5.292405398253506588e-03 9.947075946017465142e-01
>   8.000000000000000000e+00 9.794507393892835923e-03 9.902054926061071294e-01
>   6.000000000000000000e+00 2.557103864387300779e-02 9.744289613561269991e-01
>   4.000000000000000000e+00 7.076957695769577061e-02 9.292304230423041878e-01
>   2.000000000000000000e+00 1.996676820825256105e-01 8.003323179174743895e-01
>   0.000000000000000000e+00 4.226958309964479188e-01 5.773041690035520812e-01

This yields the following plot:
[Figure 1: Example plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd8mZ.png)

I would like the spacing (of the 'A' and the minus sign to be in this height (professionally manipulated using GIMP):
[Figure 2: Outcome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLkFl.png)

Note that the data used for the figures differs from the data used in the MWE.

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] instead of code fragments that we need to puzzle together ourself before being able to work on a solution for you?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I edited the post - thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837171/matplotlib-2-0-subscript-outside-of-baseline-when-super-and-subscript-are-both-u) on StackOverflow, which helped me solve my problem.

As [Stop Harming Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142055/stop-harming-monica) suggested, updating the `mathtext.FontConstantBase` parameters mentioned below helps, if you are using Arial. See [this link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/mathtext_api.html#matplotlib.mathtext.FontConstantsBase) for more information on `mathtext` classes.

The following parameter handles all superscript characters. It accepts a floating point number like `0.5`:

```
mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sup1 = 0.5
```

The following two parameters handle subscript characters. If I'm correct, `sub1` handles subscript characters, which are in the same position as superscript characters as in `X^A_B`. On the other hand, `sub2` handles unpaired subscript characters like `X_B`.

```
mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sub1 = 0.4
mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sub2 = 0.4
```

Note that the superscript character is influenced by the position of the subscript parameter in the [output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXcxN.png). I found there to be no `mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sup2`-parameter to tackle this issue.

This is the modified MWE I used:

```
# MWE update - python 3.6.4 // 3.7.2

import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.mathtext as mathtext
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Arial']
rcParams['font.size'] = 25
mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sup1 = 0.
mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sub1 = 1.
mathtext.FontConstantsBase.sub2 = 0.5

# labels in TeX-format are given in a different file in the original program

label_list=["[MX^A_B(^AY)_4]^-", "[MX(^AY)_4]^-"]

output_array = np.genfromtxt("oa.txt", dtype=float, delimiter=" ")

for ion in range(len(label_list)):
    plt.plot(output_array[:,0], output_array[:,ion], marker="s", label=r"$\mathregular{%s}$" % (label_list[ion-1]))
    plt.legend()

plt.show
```

Which produces [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXcxN.png).